# Visual Designer to Generate Javascript Code from class diagram or etc

Tags: javascript, ide, uml, designer, class-designer

I am looking for desktop executable or Browser based(if one exists) application that could generate javascript code for me from a visual designer. Something like Ext Designer that Sencha developed for their library. If there is a tool that could generate javascript code from Class Diagrams i would also love to see them. Visual Does it exactly but for Server Side code "C#" and others. I am looking for the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you ever heard of [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com/)?

Comment: why seems to be promising, but i would like to see videos, sample projects which were developed through it to convince me. The links for video, projects did not work for me on chrome

Comment: still not satisfied with the product. But i will vote you up for showing me something new